# How to add maximum score for calculation program

Tags: vba, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, windows-forms-designer

I write code for school's score calculation. When the students get overall score bellow 68, then they will have a chance to get a bonus score. The bonus score has three option that can be selected. However, when the bonus added, the total score cannot surpass 68 points. How should I done the last part?

Here's the code I've written

```
        If result < 68 Then
            If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
                bonus = 15.0
            End If
            If RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
                bonus = 10.0
            End If
            If RadioButton3.Checked = True Then
                bonus = 5.0
            End If
        End If

        total = result + bonus
```

Comment: `if result + bonus > 68 then total = 68 else total = result + bonus`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think you should keep information about if bonus was added or not

   ```
       Dim IsBonusAdded As Boolean
       IsBonusAdded = False
       If result < 68 Then
           If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
               bonus = bonus
               IsBonusAdded = True
           End If
           If RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
               bonus = 10.0
               IsBonusAdded = True
           End If
           If RadioButton3.Checked = True Then
               bonus = 5.0
               IsBonusAdded = True
           End If
       End If

       total = result + bonus
       ' total can't be more than 68 if bonus added
       If IsBonusAdded And total >=68 Then
            total = 68
       End If
   ```
2. If bonus have to be added more than one time? Then you should correct your code

   ```
       Dim IsBonusAdded As Boolean
       If result < 68 Then
           If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
               bonus = bonus + 15
               IsBonusAdded = True
           End If
           If RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
               bonus = bonus + 10
               IsBonusAdded = True
           End If
           If RadioButton3.Checked = True Then
               bonus = bonus + 5
               IsBonusAdded = True
           End If
       End If

       total = result + bonus
       ' total can't be more than 68 if bonus added
       If IsBonusAdded And total >68 Then
            total = 68
       End If
   ```